# How can I get access to the Amazon Product API with an iOS application that is still in development?

Tags: ios, amazon-product-api

I am currently trying to develop a new iOS application and am looking to pull product data off of Amazon.com. As I am signing up for the Amazon Product API, it asks me for a website or application URL for which I am using this api, but my application is still in development and I need to api to test/build it.

I do not currently have an Apple development certificate but I feel like there should be a way to get access to the Amazon Product API without publishing the application.

I am building my application in Xcode using Swift 4, and so far none of my google searches have helped me figure out a solution to this problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour around: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Website URL is an optional field. You need to describe the app you are developing, but you don’t need to provide a link to it.